# Error linking Pod Framework

Tags: xcode, youtube, cocoapods

After i added to my project the `YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper` pod, the general pod target, that includes all pods, break at linking with the message:

> ld: framework not found Pods_ChatChat clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If i create an project and add the pod YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper it compiles well as expected.
If i remove all the pods from my project and let the YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper pod, still got that same error.

The `Podfile` for the clean project and for the my stripped project is the same, and is just this:

> platform :ios, "9.0"
>
> use_frameworks!
>
> Target 'MChat' do   pod
>
> 'youtube-ios-player-helper'
>
> end

It works for the clean project but not for the stripped project.
Also, i didn't find nothing significant different in both project settings.
Both were created today with `XCode 7.3`.
The `DerivedData` folder was clean. Can't see why one works and the other no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find the problem. The problem was that i had another general pod framework. I renamed the project and didn't clean the general podFramework.